# How to find the basis of the given vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=\begin{cases}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}:x\in \mathbb{R}^+, y\in \mathbb{R}\end{cases}\bigg\}.$
Then it can be proved that under the operations $$\alpha \cdot \begin{bmatrix}x \\  y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x^{\alpha}\\ \alpha y\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\  y_1\end{bmatrix} \oplus \begin{bmatrix}x_2 \\  y_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x_1x_2 \\  y_1+y_2\end{bmatrix}$$
$V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. How to find the basis of $V$?

I know the meaning of basis and how to obtain. But the normal method doesn't work here. Please help.

Comment: What is $x^\alpha$ for $x=\alpha=0$?

Comment: @Nicolas But $x>0$ as given.

Comment: @Nicolas Since the zero vector needs to be $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$, if $x=0$ were allowed we would need $0^0=1$, which makes sense combinatorially despite $0^0$ being an indeterminate form more generally.

Comment: @MittalG $\mathbb{R}^+=[0,+\infty)$ contains $0$, so I guess that actually $x\in\mathbb{R}^{+,*}$.

Comment: @J.G.I agree, but it has to be specified. From the analysis point of view, it is perfectly fine, but here we talk about algebraic structure.

Comment: @Nicolas [$\Bbb R^+$ is used with both meanings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_real_numbers), but your notational convention is preferable.

Comment: @J.G.Well it was the purpose of my original comment: to see whether $\mathbb{R}^+$ contained 0 (and then $0^0$ has to be well-defined) or not for the author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean find *a* basis, as it's not unique.

We seek $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}c\\d\end{bmatrix}$ such that $\begin{bmatrix}a^\alpha c^\beta\\\alpha b+\beta d\end{bmatrix}$ can be any element of $V$, so e.g. $a=e,\,b=0,\,\,c=1,\,d=1$ would work, reducing the above general form to $\begin{bmatrix}e^\alpha\\\beta\end{bmatrix}$.

Edot: as @Christoph notes, it's worth saying why a basis would be of cardinality $2$. Certainly this one is, [so they all are](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces). Even if we don't notice the isomorphism in @user126154's answer, that there are $2$ components makes the dimension being $2$ our only reasonable guess.

Answer (score 4):

The function $f(x,y)=(\log x,y)$ is an isomorphism between $V$ and $\mathbb R^2$. So a basis is formed by $v_1=f^{-1}(1,0)=(e,0)$ and $v_2=f^{-1}(0,1)=(1,1)$.